# yii2 searching two fields linked to the same table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am trying to implement searching in grid view as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw6k3BEsCCE&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF&index=11). This technique works fine when you have a single field with a relation to a particular table. However, I have a table containing two fields (resource_to_id, resource_from_id) that have a relation with another table (resources).

In the model code below I can use either $query->joinwith line to search on that field but not both. How can I implement searching for both resource fields?

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Messages;

/**
 * MessagesSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Messages`.
 */
class MessagesSearch extends Messages
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'message_read'], 'integer'],
            [['subject', 'message', 'time_sent', 'resource_to_id', 'resource_from_id'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Messages::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->joinwith('resourceFrom');
        //$query->joinwith('resourceTo');

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'time_sent' => $this->time_sent,
            'message_read' => $this->message_read,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subject', $this->subject])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'message', $this->message])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'resources.resource_name', $this->resource_to_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'resources.resource_name', $this->resource_from_id])
            ;

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think ..You have to use join and put condition with `resources.resource_name=resource_to_id OR resources.resource_name=resource_from_id`

Comment: @Arshad Shaikh how do you create such a condition using yii2?

Comment: Try with this.
`$query->andWhere('resources.resource_name=resource_to_id OR resources.resource_name=resource_from_id ');`

Comment: @Arshad Shaikh that just prevents any records from showing at all. I'm new to yii2 but know SQL very well. resource_name is a string and the id fields are integers. They are totally different data so it is no wonder no records show.

Answer (score 0):

In search function you need use alias of join table like this:

```
$query->joinWith(['resourceFrom from', 'resourceTo to']);
```

Then fix andFilterWhere condition:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'from.resource_name', $this->resource_from_id])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'to.resource_name', $this->resource_to_id]);
```

Comment: This gives the error: Unknown column 'to.resource_name' in 'where clause'.

The resource_name field is in the resources table and the resource_from_id and resource_to_id fields are in the messages table.

Removing the aliases and reverting the filter back to the way it was gets rid of the error but allows searching only on the resource_from field.

Comment: What version of yii2? Need min 2.0.7. Try update it. And print you db query from debug panel.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.12. This is the query:
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` LEFT JOIN `resources` `from` ON `messages`.`resource_from_id` = `from`.`id` WHERE `resources`.`resource_name` LIKE '%e%'

Comment: I simulate your problem in code. I recive this query:
    SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` LEFT JOIN `resources` `from` ON `messages`.`resource_from_id` = `from`.`id` LEFT JOIN `resources` `to` ON `messages`.`resource_to_id` = `to`.`id` WHERE `to`.`resource_name` LIKE '%resource1%' LIMIT 20
Try compare with my code:
https://pastebin.com/nVFxzz3m https://pastebin.com/RvNMNJnp https://pastebin.com/uYAEJ8HR https://pastebin.com/E7VjUmi8 https://pastebin.com/d8zu0P1r